# What system file do I have to manipulate to create macros?

Tags: ubuntu, macros, ubuntu-12.04

For example, I want to list all files in current working directory in detailed form  `ls -l` instead of the usual `ls` format without having to type out the option every single time. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "macro", in bash is defined as "alias". From `man bash` (somewhere at the line 3744):

> ```
> alias [-p] [name[=value] ...]
>           Alias with no arguments or with the -p option prints the list of
>           aliases in the form alias name=value on standard  output.   When
>           arguments  are supplied, an alias is defined for each name whose
>           value is given.  A trailing space in  value causes the next word
>           to be checked for alias substitution when the alias is expanded.
>           For each name in the argument list for which no  value  is  sup‐
>           plied,  the  name  and  value  of  the  alias is printed.  Alias
>           returns true unless a name is given for which no alias has  been
>           defined.
> ```

You can create an alias in `~/.bash_aliases` file as follow:

```
alias ls="ls -l"
```

Also, in Ubuntu 12.04 there is already an alias for `ls` in `~/.bashrc` file that you can update as you wish. To find it, search for this line:

```
alias ls="ls --color=auto"
```

and change it to:

```
alias ls="ls --color=auto -l"
```

More about [How to create a permanent “alias”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414/147044)

Comment: Shell functions are more flexible than aliases.

Comment: @KeithThompson I agree, but this is not the case in my opinion.